# Count the number of possible paths (branches) through a code

Tags: r

My task is to define the function numOfBranches, which counts the number of possible branches (paths) through a code, e.g.:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
  sqrt(x)
}
```

has only 1 branch through the function, while

```
fun2 <- function(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    return(sqrt(x))
  } else {
    return(sqrt(as.complex(x)))
  }
}
```

has 2 branches through the function, and

```
fun3 <- function(x, y) {
  if (x > 0) {
    print("X is a positive number")
    if (y > 0) {
      print("Both numbers are positive")
    }
  }
}
```

has 4 branches through the function.

Example results of function should look like those:

```
numOfBranches(fun1)
numOfBranches(fun2)
numOfBranches(fun3)
numOfBranches(plot)
numOfBranches(`if`)
numOfBranches(plot.default)
numOfBranches(data.frame)
log2(numOfBranches(data.frame)) # loads of conditional statements
```

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2048
[1] 2.199023e+12
[1] 41
```

I have tried to count the number of "if" in the function codes. I have started with creating checkForSymbol function (below), to detect "if". As for now I have not found a clue how to transform fun1, fun2, fun3 codes into string. I would appreciate any hint on how I should proceed with such a task.

```
checkForSymbol <- function(lan, sym) {
    if(is.symbol(lan)) {
    return(identical(lan, as.symbol(sym)))
  }
}
```

Comment: The `body` function is likely to be helpful.  Statements other than `if` could create paths through a function.

Comment: How are you defining "number of branches"? If you are talking about the number of possible execution paths and you want your code to apply to arbitrary functions then the function that you are trying to write might be theoretically impossible. For example, the problem of determining if a section of code is reachable is known to be undecidable.

Comment: I define "number of branches" as a number of combination of outputs that may appear in the console. E.g. for fun3 you can have:

>f3(3,4)
[1] "X is a positive number"
[1] "Both numbers are positive"

> f3(-3,-4)

> f3(-3,4)

> f3(3,-4)
[1] "X is a positive number".

It counts for 4 paths.

Comment: What makes you think that such a function is possible to write? Also -- using your definition, wouldn't the number of branches for `data.frame` be infinite since there are infinitely many possible data frames? Where does `2.199023e+12` come from?

Comment: @Dew, by your definition, this function:  `function(x) print(x)` would have a huge number of branches, because each value of `x` could lead to different output.  Even in practice you don't know what code will be executed, because R will call different methods depending on the class of `x`.

Comment: I got those outputs as exemplorary.

I follow the logic for:
numOfBranches(fun1)
numOfBranches(fun2)
numOfBranches(fun3)
numOfBranches(plot)
numOfBranches(`if`)


I don't know the source for:
numOfBranches(plot.default)
numOfBranches(data.frame)
log2(numOfBranches(data.frame))

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking this, but short of writing a partial R compiler and using it to find and analyze a [control-flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph) for the function, I don't see how you would be able to write such a function (and even then, it won't always work due to undecidability results). Is this a homework project for a class in compiler design?

Comment: @JohnColeman, this is a homework project for Advanced R classes. I was thinking that it can be an example of AST analysis (Syntactic tree analysis). Thank you for the hint with the control-flow graph - I will check this.

Comment: Good luck with the project. Sounds interesting. As @Limey indicated above, it is easy enough to grab the code using `body` (although in some cases uninformative if the function is just a wrapper for C code).

Comment: I have resolved it with body and "if" counting. Thanks for your help.